# mysqli_sql_exception #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: php, mysql, model, codeigniter-4, mysql-error-1111

I am using codeigniter 4. I want to sum this data from my model.

```
pow(data_training.area-avg(area),2)
```

so I type like this :

```
sum(pow(data_training.area-avg(area),2))
```

but it's turn out like this:

[image]

Please tell me how to sum the data values. Here is my full code :

```
public function getVariance() {
     return $this->db->table('data_training')
     ->select('pow(data_training.area-avg(area),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as areaVariance, pow(majorAxis-avg(majorAxis),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as majorAxisVariance, pow(minorAxis-avg(minorAxis),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as minorAxisVariance, pow(eccentricity-avg(eccentricity),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as eccentricityVariance, pow(convexArea-avg(convexArea),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as convexAreaVariance, pow(extent-avg(extent),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as extentVariance, pow(perimeter-avg(perimeter),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as perimeterVariance')
     ->groupBy('kelas')
     ->get()->getResultArray();
    }
```

and here is my query that worked. So I tried to translate it to php code but i don't know how.

```
select sum(pow(dtr.area-atr.area,2))/(jml-1) as AreaVariance, sum(pow(dtr.majorAxis-atr.majorAxis,2))/(jml-1) as majorAxisVariance, sum(pow(dtr.minorAxis-atr.minorAxis,2))/(jml-1) as minorAxisVariance, sum(pow(dtr.eccentricity-atr.eccentricity,2))/(jml-1) as eccentricityVariance, sum(pow(dtr.convexArea-atr.convexArea,2))/(jml-1) as convexAreaVariance, sum(pow(dtr.extent-atr.extent,2))/(jml-1) as extentVariance, sum(pow(dtr.perimeter-atr.perimeter,2))/(jml-1) as perimeter, dtr.kelas from data_training dtr join ( select count(area) as jml,avg(area) as area, avg(majorAxis) as majorAxis, avg(minorAxis) as minorAxis, avg(eccentricity) as eccentricity, avg(convexArea) as convexArea, avg(extent) as extent, avg(perimeter) as perimeter, kelas from data_training group by kelas) atr on dtr.kelas = atr.kelas group by dtr.kelas;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries.
You can rewrite your getVariance() function:

```
public function getVariance() {
    $subquery = $this->db->table('data_training')
        ->select('count(area) as jml, avg(area) as area, avg(majorAxis) as majorAxis, avg(minorAxis) as minorAxis, avg(eccentricity) as eccentricity, avg(convexArea) as convexArea, avg(extent) as extent, avg(perimeter) as perimeter, kelas')
        ->groupBy('kelas');

    return $this->db->table('data_training dtr')
        ->select('sum(pow(dtr.area-atr.area,2))/(jml-1) as AreaVariance, sum(pow(dtr.majorAxis-atr.majorAxis,2))/(jml-1) as majorAxisVariance, sum(pow(dtr.minorAxis-atr.minorAxis,2))/(jml-1) as minorAxisVariance, sum(pow(dtr.eccentricity-atr.eccentricity,2))/(jml-1) as eccentricityVariance, sum(pow(dtr.convexArea-atr.convexArea,2))/(jml-1) as convexAreaVariance, sum(pow(dtr.extent-atr.extent,2))/(jml-1) as extentVariance, sum(pow(dtr.perimeter-atr.perimeter,2))/(jml-1) as perimeter, dtr.kelas')
        ->join("({$subquery->getCompiledSelect()} atr)", 'dtr.kelas = atr.kelas', 'left')
        ->groupBy('dtr.kelas')
        ->get()
        ->getResultArray();
}
```

Comment: "mysqli_sql_exception #1064"
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'atr) ON `dtr`.`kelas` = `atr`.`kelas`
GROUP BY `dtr`.`kelas`' at line 5 ---

still error. can you tell me which thing makes the error, please?

Comment: change the join line to: `-> join("{$subquery->getCompiledSelect()} as atr", 'dtr.kelas = atr.kelas', 'left')`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    public function getVariance() {
    $subquery = $this->db->table("data_training")
        ->select("kelas, COUNT ( kelas ) kelas_count, SUM ( area ) sum_area, AVG ( area ) avg_area, SUM ( majoraxis ) sum_majoraxis, AVG ( majoraxis ) avg_majoraxis, SUM ( minoraxis ) sum_minoraxis, AVG ( minoraxis ) avg_minoraxis, SUM ( eccentricity ) sum_eccentricity, AVG ( eccentricity ) avg_eccentricity, SUM ( convexarea ) sum_convexarea, AVG ( convexarea ) avg_convexarea, SUM ( extent ) sum_extent, AVG ( extent ) avg_extent, SUM ( perimeter ) sum_perimeter, AVG ( perimeter ) avg_perimeter")
        ->groupBy("kelas");

    return $this->db->newQuery()->select("POW( ( sum_area - avg_area ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS areaVariance, POW( ( sum_majoraxis - avg_majoraxis ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS majorAxisVariance, POW( ( sum_minoraxis - avg_minoraxis ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS minorAxisVariance, POW( ( sum_eccentricity - avg_eccentricity ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS eccentricityVariance, POW( ( sum_convexarea - avg_convexarea ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS convexAreaVariance, POW( ( sum_extent - avg_extent ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS extentVariance, POW( ( sum_perimeter - avg_perimeter ), 2 ) / ( kelas_count - 1 ) AS perimeterVariance")->fromSubquery($subquery, 'dt')->get()->getResultArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL if you `group by` columns, say c1, c2, ..., then those columns can be used as aggregates. In your select clause you cannot use columns directly unless they are aggregates. Non-aggregate columns may still be used as if they were aggregates. With that in mind, let's see your `select` clause, which I share here unchanged, except for a few newlines that helps one reading it:

```
pow(data_training.area-avg(area),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as areaVariance,
pow(majorAxis-avg(majorAxis),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as majorAxisVariance,
pow(minorAxis-avg(minorAxis),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as minorAxisVariance,
pow(eccentricity-avg(eccentricity),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as eccentricityVariance,
pow(convexArea-avg(convexArea),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as convexAreaVariance,
pow(extent-avg(extent),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as extentVariance,
pow(perimeter-avg(perimeter),2)/(count(kelas)-1) as perimeterVariance
```

Since you grouped by `kelas`, it can be used directly. From this perspective, `count(kelas)` is misleading, you could use `count(*)` instead. But this is not the cause of your error. The cause of your error is that you are using non-aggregate fields as if they were aggregates, notably:

- `area`
- `majorAxis`
- `minorAxist`
- `eccentricity`
- `convexArea`
- `extent`
- `perimeter`

To illustrate, let me give you an example:

```
pow(data_training.area-avg(area),2)/(count(kelas)-1)
```

Here, `data_training.area` is a non-aggregate column used as if it was an aggregate column. We have already grouped by `kelas`, but not by `area`, so what would `area` mean in this case, especially if there are multiple possible values. `avg(area)` makes sense, it means that we take all the values of `area` from the group and compute their average. So, `data_training.area` cannot be used by itself, whereas `avg(area)` makes perfect sense.

I do not know what you wanted to compute with your query, so I do not know what your solution will be unless you provide further contextual information, but it's perfectly clear that the cause of the specific error you have mentioned is that you treat non-aggregates as if they were aggregates.